# Rails: Truncating HTML-tagged text while preserving link text during truncation in a database column

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, truncate

I have a database column named `comment` that stores comments containing HTML tags.

To shorten large texts and display them fully in a pop-up, I'm using the `truncate(comment, length: 50, escape: false)` function.

Let's consider two examples:

Example 1:
The `comment` column contains the following plain text with HTML tags. By using `escape: false`, HTML tags are not truncated, and the text is displayed correctly, including any formatting such as bold:

```
<strong>123</strong><br>
\\\<br>
<strong>test</strong>
```

Example 2:
In this case, I'm using an `href` tag to create a link, but the `escape` behavior is not functioning as expected. Instead of recognizing it as an HTML tag, it treats it as plain text:

```
<a href="/uploads/attachments/2211/test.pdf" target="_blank">ClickToOpenFile</a>
```

After truncation, it displays something like:

```
<a href="/uploads/attachments/2..
```

However, the desired outcome is to only truncate the text inside the `<a>` tag, keeping the link text "ClickToOpenFile" intact.

I have attempted using `raw` and `html_safe`, but unfortunately, they did not provide the desired results.

Comment: So, what is exactly a question? "Why truncate works as it works?" or "how to truncate an inner text in HTML"?.

Comment: It is exactly expected behaviour of truncate function. See the docs and examples: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate.

Comment: @VasilyKolesnikov How to truncate an inner text in HTML that would be the question

Comment: It could be achieved with https://github.com/hgmnz/truncate_html gem. Rails doesn't do this work, at least in `truncate` method that says: "Care should be taken if text contains HTML tags or entities, because truncation may produce invalid HTML (such as unbalanced or incomplete tags)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With github.com/hgmnz/truncate_html gem:

```
some_html = '<ul><li><a href="http://whatever">This is a link</a></li></ul>'
truncate_html(some_html, length: 15, omission: '...(continued)')
  => <ul><li><a href="http://whatever">This...(continued)</a></li></ul>
```